# Emacs insert centered comment block

Tags: emacs, macros, latex, elisp, center

I would like to create a macro for emacs that will insert a latex comment block with some centerd text like:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%                Comment 1                    %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%           Comment 2 Commenttext 3           %%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Is this possible in `emacs-lisp`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Emacs comes with the command `comment-box` for this purpose. It produces centered comment boxes, although the width of the box varies depending on the content. E.g., with the region set around the following line:

```
This is a comment
```

when you call `M-x comment-box` the text is transformed to:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; This is a comment ;;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

I use a modifed version that places the comment box around the current line if the region isn't active, and then steps out of the comment afterwards. It also temporarily reduces the fill-column, so the comment box is not wider than your longest line:

```
(defun ty-box-comment (beg end &optional arg) 
  (interactive "*r\np")
  (when (not (region-active-p))
    (setq beg (point-at-bol))
    (setq end (point-at-eol)))
  (let ((fill-column (- fill-column 6)))
    (fill-region beg end))
  (comment-box beg end arg)
  (ty-move-point-forward-out-of-comment))

(defun ty-point-is-in-comment-p ()
  "t if point is in comment or at the beginning of a commented line, otherwise nil"
  (or (nth 4 (syntax-ppss))
      (looking-at "^\\s *\\s<")))

(defun ty-move-point-forward-out-of-comment ()
  "Move point forward until it's no longer in a comment"
  (while (ty-point-is-in-comment-p)
    (forward-char)))
```

Comment: For the sake of completenes, maybe you should include the definition of `ty-move-point-forward-out-of-comment` or replace it with a standard command (`forward-paragraph`?) so that non-lispers can use it right away...

Comment: Oops, didn't notice I had some personal functions there. Fixed!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a yasnippet that you can use:

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# name: huge_comment
# key: hc
# --
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%${1:$(repeat-char (- 33 (/ (length yas-text) 2)) " ")}$1${1:$(repeat-char (- 74 (length yas-text) (- 33 (/ (length yas-text) 2))) " ")}%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
$0
```

How to use it: type `hc`, call `yas-expand` and start typing the text. It will re-center itself
automatically.

This snippet will work from `latex-mode` or `text-mode`. I've noticed however a bug that
messes up the cursor position if you're using AUCTeX. In that case, you can momentarily switch
to `text-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

The question was whether it is possible in emacs-lisp. Yes it is. There are several ways to do it.
I will show one way where you can also comment several lines of text.
Maybe, in the first line there is the title of the part of text and in the second one there is the author of this part.

A better way would be to advice `LaTeX-indent-line` function. This way you could edit the comment text and re-indent. When I find time I will show you also this variant.

Usage: Write your comment as clear text. Mark text as region with the mouse and then run the following command.

```lisp
(defun LaTeX-centered-comment (b e)
  "Convert region into centered comment."
  (interactive "r")
  (let* ((n (count-lines b e)))
    (goto-char b)
    (beginning-of-line)
    (insert-char ?% fill-column)
    (insert ?\n)
    (setq b (point))
    (center-line n)
    (goto-char b)
    (loop for i from 1 upto n do
      (replace-region (point) (+ (point) 3) "%%%")
      (end-of-line)
      (insert-char ?\  (max 0 (- fill-column (- (point) (line-beginning-position)) 3)))
      (insert "%%%")
      (forward-line))
    (insert-char ?% fill-column)
    (insert ?\n)
    ))
```