# How can I create titles comments automatically with Emacs?

Tags: emacs

With Emacs, how can I automatically create comments titles like this one:

```
;;###############################################################################
;;                           title
;;###############################################################################
```

The purpose is to comment code (in this case Emacs configuration file) by sectioning the code in a clear way. I don't want to do this by hand because it takes time and it's often not perfectly centered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs insert centered comment block](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21042321/emacs-insert-centered-comment-block)

Comment: Here's how I structure my elisp code with comments: http://abo-abo.github.io/lispy/#sec-3-30 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
M-x comment-box
```

is the solution